# Generating preview image thumbnails of uploaded files on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm using Rails to create a website that allows users to upload document files with various file formats (pdf, doc, docx, ppt, pptx, xls, xlsx, png, jpg, jpeg) and store them on aws S3.
I'm using Carrierwave to directly upload files to S3, and everything works well so far. Uploaded files are nicely stored in S3.

But now, I want to display preview images (thumbnail images) for uploaded files. I've tried several different methods by manipulating Carrierwave configuration, but it seems like generating thumbnail images only works on PDF files, not other file formats. Can anyone please give me any insight to make this work? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rather than generating thumbnails within the application, you could consider using systems that can generate thumbnails on-the-fly, such as:

- [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/)
- [Imgix](http://imgix.com/)

Comment: Cloudinary will be costlier than implementing own image infrastructure in AWS. There is a solution available in AWS for on the fly image thumbnail generation and applying other transformation for images on the fly which is explained here https://youtu.be/VuZNvCGIilI

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you:
http://guides.railsgirls.com/thumbnails

I also found a tutorial that says you should be able to uncomment some code in the image_uploader file.

```
version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_fill => [50, 50]
end
```

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/rails-image-upload-using-carrierwave-in-a-rails-app--cms-25183

See if either of these solutions work.

Answer (score 0):

As John wrote, for your images you can try generating thumbnails on the fly with a solution like Cloudinary's [jQuery image upload](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/jquery_image_upload) library. This solution enables image uploading to the cloud. Uploaded images are stored safely in the cloud with secure backups and revision history, utilizing Amazon's S3 service.

Cloudinary's jQuery library also enables on the fly generation of thumbnails.

Here is a sample code that creates a 150x100 thumbnail of an uploaded image and updates an input field with the public ID of this image.

```
$('.cloudinary-fileupload').bind('cloudinarydone', function(e, data) {  
$('.preview').html(
$.cloudinary.image(data.result.public_id, 
  { format: data.result.format, version: data.result.version, 
    crop: 'fill', width: 150, height: 100 })
);    
$('.image_public_id').val(data.result.public_id);    
 return true;
});
```

Here you can find some [Ruby on Rails examples](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/blob/master/samples/photo_album/app/views/photos/new_direct.html.erb)